# Static methods and designing for inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism, static-methods

I am unclear on what is the best way to design a class with static methods that are meant to be overridable.  I will try to explain with an example.

---

We have a class `Goat` with a method `can_climb`.  (By the way this is Python 3, in Python 2 I would write `class Goat(object):`.)

```
class Goat:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        ...

    def can_climb(self, mountain):
        return mountain.steepness < 10

billy = Goat("Billy")
if billy.can_climb(mount_everest):
    print("wow Billy, impressive")
```

This works as intended, but the method `can_climb` doesn't use `self`.  It seems cleaner to make it a static method, and pylint even gives a warning for the above method. So let's change that:

```
class Goat:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def can_climb(mountain):
        return mountain.steepness < 10

billy = Goat("Billy")
if billy.can_climb(mount_everest):
    print("wow Billy, impressive")
```

`billy.can_climb` near the end can instead be `Goat.can_climb` and it won't make a difference in this example.  Some people might even see it as being clearer and more direct to call a static method via its class and not an instance.

However, this leads to a subtle error when we use inheritance and polymorphism is introduced:

```
class Goat:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def can_climb(mountain):
        return mountain.steepness < 10

class MountaineeringGoat(Goat):
    @staticmethod
    def can_climb(mountain):
        return True

billy = get_ourselves_a_goat_called_billy()
if Goat.can_climb(mount_everest):     # bug
    print("wow Billy, impressive")
```

The code that calls `Goat.can_climb` knows that `billy` is an instance of `Goat` and makes the erroneous assumption that its type is `Goat`, when it could really be any subtype of `Goat`.  Or maybe it incorrectly assumes that subclasses won't override a static method.

This seems to me like an easy mistake to make; perhaps `Goat` didn't have any subclasses at the time this bug was introduced, so the bug was not noticed.

---

How can we design and document a class so that this sort of bug is avoided?  In particular, should `can_climb` from this example be a static method or should something else be used instead?

Comment: You've already demonstrated how to avoid the bug; unless you need a specific class, call methods (and attributes) on the instance. And have unit tests that detect functionality regressions.

Comment: I'm not yet convinced that my design is the best design. Perhaps I should really use an instance method?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm looking for ways to avoid this problem from the class's side rather than the caller's side if that is possible.

Comment: You can't, if the caller explicitly selects the class, that is what (and should!) get called, there's nothing to fix. Even if you make it an instance method, the caller could still do `Goat.can_climb(billy, ...)`. As for the *"best design"*, that's hard to say with an abstract example and at least partly opinion based.

Answer (score 34):

Inheritance clearly means a knowledge of the base class. `@staticmethod` is ignorant of the class it is 'attached' to(hence they earlier-not now-a-days-called it 'unbound;' now technically `@staticmethod` is not a method at all; it is a function.

But `@classmethod` is fully aware of the class it is attached to; it is technically not a function, but a method.

Why then `@staticmethod` at all? It is inherited in a derived class, but as said earlier, without the knowledge of base class; we can use it 'as such' as if we have defined it in the derived class.

Non-technically speaking `@classmethod`s are 'bounded'; `@staticmethod`s are NOT.

Had anybody asked me I would have suggested the name `@staticfunction` for `@staticmethod`.

Additionally, to ensure that the latest staticmethod is called, you may use `type(billy).can_climb(mountain)` or `billy.__class__.can_climb(mountain)` (although `type(billy)` is more pythonic it seems), which calls the staticmethod from `billy`'s (sub)class. If it's not overridden, it would use the base-classe's staticmethod.

Comment: Since you mentioned more than once, can you describe what is technical difference between method and function?

Comment: @ali A function is class-less, a method is a function inside of a class. This is a language agnostic CompSci thing

Comment: I think you meant `@classmethod` instead of `@staticfunction` at the end.  Also, `@staticmethod` is _not_ inherited nor does it have access to the class members.

Comment: @whitey04 I just created a subclass for a class that has `@staticmethod` in it, and this subclass *did* inherit the method wrapped in `staticmethod` in the base class.

Comment: @Jonathan this definition of function (class-less) and method (class-attached) might be common/conventional, but it is not universal/agnostic across all languages: eg Julia has different notions of what a method is: "A definition of one possible behavior for a function is called a method." (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/)

Comment: The `@staticmethod` may be ignorant of the class it is attached to, but the base class is not ignorant of the `@staticmethod`'s attached to its subclasses:
```python
class A:

    def foo(self):
        return self._foo()

class B(A):

    @staticmethod
    def _foo():
        return "B"

class C(A):

    @staticmethod
    def _foo():
        return "C"
```
In the above code, `self._foo()` will call the proper `@staticmethod` attached to the actual subclass

Answer (score 7):

Actually, at least with Python 3.8, I **do** see a difference between `billy.can_climb` and `Goat.can_climb` and as far as I can see the code does not make the erroneous assumption that the type of `billy` is `Goat`:

```py
class Mountain:
        def __init__(self, steepness):
            self.steepness = steepness

class Goat:
    @staticmethod
    def can_climb(mountain):
        return mountain.steepness < 10

class MountaineeringGoat(Goat):
    @staticmethod
    def can_climb(mountain):
        return True

def get_ourselves_a_goat_called_billy():
    return MountaineeringGoat()

mount_everest = Mountain(100)

billy = get_ourselves_a_goat_called_billy()
if billy.can_climb(mount_everest):
    print("wow Billy, impressive")
```

In the above code, `billy.can_climb(mount_everest)` actually calls `MountaineeringGoat.can_climb(mount_everest)` and I do see this output:
**`wow Billy, impressive`**.